# How to get Google Calendar to send notifications and daily agenda again?

Tags: google-calendar

I configured Google Calendar to send me a daily agenda email (to my Gmail account) as well as reminders for my events, and for the past month or so I have received no emails from Google Calendar at all. I searched around on the web and apparently others are having this problem as well. Is there a workaround to get daily agenda emails and event notifications until Google fixes this problem?

Comment: Where are you seeing "others are having this problem"? I'm seeing daily agendas in my inbox.

Comment: See http://www.google.me/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=3d7fef26e067ec32&hl=en Also, note that that link links to another link showing that it is a known issue for Google and listing a couple of fixes that were reported to work for some people (not me). They just haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: Just making sure that you've checked the Notification settings of that particular calendar and they still have the Daily Agenda ticked...

Comment: Yes, the settings are correct, and I've toggled them repeatedly.